# JOptionPane showOptionDialog shows up blank randomly

Tags: java, swing

I took a few Java programming classes in college but it's been a few years so I'm pretty rusty. I decided to ask my brother for a programming task. He asked me to write a program to quiz him on the elemental type effectiveness in the Pokemon games. The code works for the most part, but for some reason the Option Dialog box is blank sometimes. I have a title, but the rest is a gray box. The part that's most confusing to me is that I have a println() right before it and it prints the correct phrase when the pane is empty.

Here is my code output:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Quiz {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    try{
        /*creates the matrix of the different types 
         *and their effectiveness to each other. 0
         *represents "Not very effective", 1 is "Neutral"
         *2 is "Super effective", 3 is "No Damage"
        */

        int[][] myTypeArray = 
            {{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
                {2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0},
                {1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
                {1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2},
                {1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
                {1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1},
                {1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0},
                {3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1},
                {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2},
                {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1},
                {1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1 ,1, 0, 1, 1},
                {1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1},
                {1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1},
                {1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 3, 1},
                {1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1},
                {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3},
                {1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0},
                {1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1}};

        //Names for the types
        String[] myTypeNamesArray = {"Normal", "Fighting", "Flying", "Poison", "Ground", 
                "Rock", "Bug", "Ghost", "Steel", "Fire", "Water", 
                "Grass", "Electric", "Psychic", "Ice", "Dragon", 
                "Dark", "Fairy"};


        //loops the message panes until they get a wrong answer
        for(int i = 0; i > -1; i++){

            //Two integers to randomly select one of the 18 different types
            int num1 = (int)(Math.random()*18);
            int num2 = (int)(Math.random()*18);

            //Creates JOptionPane to show the two randomed types and get input
            //Name of the buttons
            Object[] buttons = { "Not Very Effective", "Neutral", "Super Effective", "No Damage" };

            //Test output for asking them how effective type 1 is vs type 2
            System.out.println(num1 + " " + num2 + " " + "How effective is " + 
                    myTypeNamesArray[num1] + " against " + myTypeNamesArray[num2] + "?    " + 
                    "the answer was " + (String)buttons[myTypeArray[num1][num2]] + ".   " + i);

            // **HERE IS WHERE THE MESSAGE IS BLANK SOMETIMES**
            int answer = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "How effective is " + 
                    myTypeNamesArray[num1] + " against " + myTypeNamesArray[num2] + "?",
                    "Pokemon Type Effectiveness Quiz", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, 
                    JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, buttons, buttons[0]);


            //Test their answers                     
            if(answer == myTypeArray[num1][num2]){
            } else if(!(answer == myTypeArray[num1][num2])) {
                // **THIS IS ALSO BLANK SOMETIMES **
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry, the answer was " + 
                        (String)buttons[myTypeArray[num1][num2]] + ". You said " + 
                        buttons[answer] + "\nYou got " + i + " correct.");
                break;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("The error was " + e);
    }

}//end main

}
```

Comment: Run the code on the Swing Event Thread or EDT by calling `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {public void run() { ... your code goes in here ...}});`

Comment: The randomness of the selected indexes doesn't tell you something about the randomness of the blank dialogs?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I'll look into it. I've never learned/heard of that before

Comment: @JuanManuel: The intermittent nature of the problem suggests a threading issue.

Comment: @JuanManuel They do not. I've marked down the println outputs and there is not pattern to when the box is blank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The intermittent nature of the problem suggests a threading issue. Try running your code on the Swing event thread. Something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
        doOnEventThread();
     }
  });
}

public static void doOnEventThread() {
    try{
        /*creates the matrix of the different types 
         *and their effectiveness to each other. 0
         *represents "Not very effective", 1 is "Neutral"
         *2 is "Super effective", 3 is "No Damage"
        */

        int[][] myTypeArray = 
            {{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
                {2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0},
                {1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
                {1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2},
                {1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
                {1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1},
                {1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0},
                {3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1},
                {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2},
                {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1},
                {1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1 ,1, 0, 1, 1},
                {1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1},
                {1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1},
                {1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 3, 1},
                {1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1},
                {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3},
                {1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0},
                {1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1}};

        //Names for the types
        String[] myTypeNamesArray = {"Normal", "Fighting", "Flying", "Poison", "Ground", 
                "Rock", "Bug", "Ghost", "Steel", "Fire", "Water", 
                "Grass", "Electric", "Psychic", "Ice", "Dragon", 
                "Dark", "Fairy"};


        //loops the message panes until they get a wrong answer
        for(int i = 0; i > -1; i++){

            //Two integers to randomly select one of the 18 different types
            int num1 = (int)(Math.random()*18);
            int num2 = (int)(Math.random()*18);

            //Creates JOptionPane to show the two randomed types and get input
            //Name of the buttons
            Object[] buttons = { "Not Very Effective", "Neutral", "Super Effective", "No Damage" };

            //Test output for asking them how effective type 1 is vs type 2
            System.out.println(num1 + " " + num2 + " " + "How effective is " + 
                    myTypeNamesArray[num1] + " against " + myTypeNamesArray[num2] + "?    " + 
                    "the answer was " + (String)buttons[myTypeArray[num1][num2]] + ".   " + i);

            // **HERE IS WHERE THE MESSAGE IS BLANK SOMETIMES**
            int answer = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "How effective is " + 
                    myTypeNamesArray[num1] + " against " + myTypeNamesArray[num2] + "?",
                    "Pokemon Type Effectiveness Quiz", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, 
                    JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, buttons, buttons[0]);


            //Test their answers                     
            if(answer == myTypeArray[num1][num2]){
            } else if(!(answer == myTypeArray[num1][num2])) {
                // **THIS IS ALSO BLANK SOMETIMES **
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry, the answer was " + 
                        (String)buttons[myTypeArray[num1][num2]] + ". You said " + 
                        buttons[answer] + "\nYou got " + i + " correct.");
                break;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

---

**Edit**
For more information on Swing's event thread and threading issues, please have a look at the article, [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/). But to re-iterate, whenever you find yourself up against a program misbehavior that's intermittent, that doesn't happen all the time, think "threading problem".

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have fixed it. I still don't understand how or why yet, I'll look it up, but I haven't gotten any blank panes yet.

Comment: @jjthemagicman: please see edit to answer and link for more on this.

Comment: Good to know, thanks. I read the article and it explains it pretty well.